# HTML nbsp entity not rendering as a non-breaking space

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I am updating a date formatter in a scala play application to ensure the date doesn't break onto a new line with the following:

```
 def formatDate(localDate: LocalDate, pattern: String = "d MMMM yyyy"): String = {
    val d = java.util.Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toInstant)
    create(pattern).format(d).replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;")
  }
```

The problem is that this is outputting `&nbsp;` into the page, and not the space entity - what reason could this be?

Comment: is there any parser in between the code and the display?

Comment: @Greedo - I'm not entirely sure!

Comment: Seems there is something that avoid the parsing of HTML, you can test if inserting something like `<b> foo </b>` will be printed in bold or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is inside a Twirl template.

By default, all dynamic contents is encoded for security reasons to avoid some common attacks (XSS). See here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTemplates#Escaping

You can use

```
@Html(formatDate(theDate))
```

Or better, simply use the proper character instead of the HTML character entity:

```
val nbsp = "\u00A0"
create(pattern).format(d).replaceAll(" ", nbsp)
```

---

BTW, I think the usual way of doing this, instead of hard-coding this into the application, is to use CSS rules to avoid breaking the text inside its container. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Thanks so much - the CSS way is for word-wrap: no wrap - this isn't a word, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: I was referring to the `white-space: nowrap;` CSS rule.